# Loop image animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an image that does an animation.

```
$('.user-card').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(-55px, 0)');
```

The code above moves the image from right to left 55px. I want it move to the right or first position after it has finished moving to the left.

Also, I want it to loop this action forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a class with a simple CSS3 animation, and an `animation-iteration-count` value of infinite; you can then use `addClass()` to create this animation on load of the page or as a response to an event.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yvaFL/2/)**

Comment: Very nice. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
var doForever = $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.user-card').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(-55px, 0)');
    $('.user-card').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(+55px, 0)');
doForever();
});

doForever();
```

Comment: Thanks! but after I processed your code, the image is move to right and it doesn't loop. It's like it execute the last animation. `$('.user-card').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(+55px, 0)');`